# Security Warning when running scripts - Unblock-File not unblocking file

Tags: security, powershell, powershell-ise

I suddenly started to recceive this warning when running any script on my computer:

> Run only scripts that you trust. While scripts from the internet can be useful, this script can potentially harm your computer...

Screenshot:

[image: Powershell Security Warning]

The files are not blocked.

I have

- checked in File Explorer > Properties.
- used the `Unblock-File` cmdlet to unblock as well.
- checked streams using cmdlet: `Get-Content -Path '\\Path\Script.ps1' -Stream Zone.Identifier`. No Streams found.
- used Streams.exe from Sysinternals: `streams.exe -d \\Path\Script.ps1`. No files with streams found.

Also tried to remove streams with Powershell:

```
Remove-Item -Path \\Path\Script.ps1 -Stream Zone.Identifier
```

Of course without success as there are no streams.

Execution policy is Unrestricted.

When I run Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass it works without warning.
It should, however, also work when it's unrestricted.

I honestly don't know what's going on.

Comment: Does the script reside on a network drive?

Comment: I know this is old, but this was helpful for me when i had the same problem: https://blog.netspi.com/15-ways-to-bypass-the-powershell-execution-policy/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After searching i found someone with similar issues and it was explained that Classic UNC paths will work without prompting to unblock the file:

```
\\Servername\Path...
```

However FQDN paths are not seen as safe by default and will prompt:

```
\\Servername.foo.local\Path...
```

My own testing confirms this to be correct as removing the `.foo.local` from the path causes the `Unblock-File` prompts to stop.

Comment: Months of aggravation gone in an instant. You sir are a hero.

Answer (score 0):

LGPE > gpedit.msc

> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates, >  Windows Components, > Internet Explorer>expand Internet Control Panel.
>   Security Page > Intranet Sites: Include all local (intranet) sites not listed in other zones, and then click Properties.
>   Click Enabled.
>
> Turn on automatic detection of the intranet, and then click Properties.
>   Click Disabled, and then click OK.

or registry

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\"UNCAsIntranet" = "0"
```

Comment: Yesterday edited the registry key, but no change.

Just tried with the gpedit method, rebooted, but still same issue.

Comment: LGPE? Let's Go Pikachu/Eevee?

Answer (score 0):

The correct registry keys, name and value, to treat all local sites as part of the intranet zone, are:

```
Keys:

HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap
HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap

Name:  IntranetName
Type:  DWORD
Value: 1
```

You can set this via PowerShell for the local machine (in an elevated prompt) like this:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap" -Name "IntranetName" -Type DWord -Value 1
```

See [Intranet Sites: Include all local (intranet) sites not listed in other zones](https://admx.help/?Category=InternetExplorer&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.InternetExplorer::IZ_IncludeUnspecifiedLocalSites) for more information about the group policy.

Answer (score -3):

PS doesnot allow Scripts to run on system ENV by default. 
you need to set the policy to unrestricted or remote signed
Use:
**Set-ExecutionPolicy Remotesigned**
        OR
**Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted**

Open the PS console and type this and press enter and then try running your script.

Comment: he says Execution policy is Unrestricted it means No restrictions; all Windows PowerShell scripts can be run.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176961.aspx

Comment: My execution policy is Unrestricted.
When changing execution policy to Bypass I don't receive the warning anymore.

It should, however, also work when it is Unrestricted.

Comment: so setting execution policy bypass fixed the issue only on current session or all?