# Unblock-File cmdlet is not working for Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I am having trouble using the Unblock-File cmdlet. It will not unblock any file that I specify. Here is an example of what command I am trying to run

`Unblock-File -Path "C:\test_file.txt"`

First, I check my version of Powershell installed. Check.

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      16299  967
```

Second, I check sources [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617509/unblock-a-file-with-powershell) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38584428/security-warning-when-running-scripts-unblock-file-not-unblocking-file) to make sure I have tried everything suggested to get the file to be unblocked.

I have:

1. Tried running the `Unblock-File` cmdlet.
2. Tried bypassing execution policy and running with an unrestricted execution policy.
3. Checked file permissions and properties for the file, and all permissions are available.
4. Removed `foo.local` from the pathname
5. Ran `-Stream Zone.Identifier`, with no alternate streams found.

Still cannot run the file without a Security Warning popping up. What am I missing here?

**PS**: I do not have Admin rights to this computer.

**EDIT**: List of links to try to fix this problem with the `New-SelfSignedCertificate -CloneCert $OldCert` command:

http://www.herlitz.nu/2017/11/09/find-certificates-using-powershell/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=win10-ps

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_signing?view=powershell-6

https://superuser.com/questions/174878/powershell-access-denied-to-cert-currentuser-my

https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/61yt7i/seeking_help_importing_certificates/

https://powershell.org/forums/topic/using-invoke-command-to-import-certificate-gives-access-denied/

Comment: Unblocking a file doesn't get rid of a security prompt.. It allows you to run files downloaded from the Internet.  If an executable isn't signed, it will always generate that warning.

Comment: So I have to basically *certify* any code I write in order for the message to dissappear?

Comment: If it's an executable, yes.  If you have an internal CA, it shouldn't be too bad to deploy the public cert to your hosts and sign your executable through whatever IDE you're using.

Comment: Ok. I will have to research how to do that. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I got a list of all certs on the computer, and tried the `New-SelfSignedCertificate -CloneCert $OldCert` command. Access Denied for every cert. I have about hit my limit, lol.